# How to stop white cursor from moving in curses console in c++

Tags: c++, console, ncurses, curses

I'm am currently trying to develop a simple rpg using the curses library that I installed on my Ubuntu distribution. The problem I am running into is that I still have a white cursor blinking on my screen even though the lib is initialized. And when I press key down, the cursor moves down a line and sometimes two at once randomly. Is there any way of preventing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use something like:

```
system("setterm -cursor off");
```

With the `cstdlib`library

Comment: Perfect ! It worked flawlessly. But now I have two problems, first of all when I exit my programme the cursor doesn't come back, I have to restart my console window. The second issue is that my noecho() function call at the beginning of my code doesn't work and when I type in letters, they appear on the screen. Do you have any ideas on how to solve these two issues ?

Comment: use the sursor on when you echo something and turn off after when you want to stop blink

Answer (score 1):

Use [`curs_set`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-curs_set) to hide the cursor:

> The **`curs_set`** routine sets the cursor state  to  invisible,
>          normal, or very visible for visibility equal to 0, 1, or 2
>          respectively.  If the terminal supports the visibility requested, the previous cursor state is returned; otherwise,
>          **`ERR`** is returned.

When your program calls [`endwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-endwin), ncurses automatically restores the cursor visibility.

Regarding the cursor moving "randomly", no one can answer that without seeing your (small) sample program.